swiftUI cast back struct type from opaque view
How to get LoginView from:
SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<Patient.LoginView, SwiftUI._EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Swift.Optional<Patient.MySceneDelegate>>>, SwiftUI._EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Swift.Optional<Patient.MyNavigationViewModel>>>, Patient.ProtectedView>

I don't get how to cast the object back to LoginView and call a specific method called func attemptLogin() async inside this object.
Is there a way to achieve it?

You are doing something very wrong if you need to call a View's method that is not self. This is an XY Problem. Please explain why you want to do this.

You dont. Views shouldn’t be held in variables

Yes, this is very wrong.
The method has to be contained in a ViewModel (that doesn't exist) and create a Unit Test from it.
For the other hand, cover the rest of the View with .accessibilityIdentifiers to check texts, colors, etc.
I was not able to add a ViewModel but I got permission to make it.
Thanks for remarking it is very wrong.
Even with that in mind and knowing it is something wrong, I am still curious if this is possible to achieve or not.
